Delete meetings from the past without sending notifications to participants
in the "old" Outlook it was possible to delete calendar entries from the past without sending any notifications:

if I was a participant in a meeting, the deletion in my calendar did not trigger a mail to the organizer, because the meeting was anyway in the past
if I was the organizer of a meeting, the deletion in my calendar did also not trigger cancellation to the participants, because the meeting was anyway in the past

With the "new" Outlook (i. e. the version which looks bascially like the Outlook web-app and seems to be the standard now), the scenario #1 from above is still the same. But in scenario #2 from above, Outlook sends a cancellation to all participants although it is a meeting from the past.
This cancellation is unfortunately also sent if I use Power-Automate (see screenshot). Is there a way to delete/ archive a calendar entry from the past without sending any notifications/ cancellations?

